# Is HMVC Codeigniter SEO friendly?

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo, uri, hmvc

I am using `HMVC CI`. these URLs all are the same and show duplicated contents.

```
example.com

example.com/welcome

example.com/welcome/welcome

example.com/welcome/welcome/index
```

Can i solve this issue and make my project SEO friendly? i think all modules have this issue!

Comment: explore CI routes

Comment: `welcome` is your controller name? and in this url `example.com/welcome/welcome` welcome is controller name and welcome is function name???

Comment: Yes, in fact its my module name and my controller name and the method name is 'index'.

Comment: If i declare any other module, this issue will be appear. for example: example.com example.com/article example.com/article/article example.com/article/article/index

Comment: one more question `example.com/welcome/welcome/index` in this url, ist welcome is your folder name, second welcome is your controller name and INDEX is your function name right.

Comment: you need to use these route in config/route.php file  `$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['welcome/index'] = "welcome/index";`

Comment: Yes, in this case, the module name and controller name are same. also module folder name is same as controller name.

Comment: Yes, but this issue repeat in all of modules and URLs, not just default controller.

Comment: u need to define for other module as well.

Comment: This is  for non-hmvc uri architecture, but give a try and adopt first rule to your application structure. Check this [CI .htaccess](https://github.com/Tpojka/general-ci-htaccess/blob/master/.htaccess) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use routing to rewrite the urls.

```
$route['journals'] = 'blogs';
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

So your URL's can be anything you want them to be.

The duplicated content issue can also be solved by setting a canonical url for each page in the controller. You can read about canonical urls here:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

But basically you add a meta link in the header to say what page this should be called for SEO:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/my-preferred-url" />
```

Finally, you could rename your modules, controllers and functions to more accurately reflect what you would like to see in the url.